# Ошибка на сайте из-за двух дочерних элементов в меню

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu

При добавлении более одного дочернего элемента в горизонтальное меню сайта, пропадает само меню и весь контент, который идёт после него. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На скриншоте видно, что в разделе "Мастика, праймер, битум" много дочерних элементов, но если я хоть один добавлю в раздел "Кровельные материалы", то результат будет таков: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чём может быть причина? Для дополнительной информации уточню: горизонтальное меню - дочерние элементы всплывают при наведении мыши, в вертикальном меню дочерние элементы появляются по клику (с вертикальным меню всё хорошо, всё исправно работает). Движок wordpress, шаблон - Outlet. Никакие плагины относящиеся к Меню не используются.

Прикрепляю html код меню без двух дочерних элементов.

```
    <header class="sub-menu-head">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <nav id="sub-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/rulonnye-krovelnye-materialy/">Тест</a></li>
<li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/gipsokarton/">Гипсокартон</a></li>
<li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/">Мастика, праймер, битум</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/mastika-bitumnaya-aquamast/">Мастика битумная AquaMast</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/mastika-bitumno-rezinovaya-aquamast/">Мастика битумно-резиновая AquaMast</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/mastika-gidroizolyacionnaya-texnonikol-24-mgtn/">Мастика гидроизоляционная ТЕХНОНИКОЛЬ №24 (МГТН)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/mastika-mktn-bitumno-polimernaya/">Мастика МКТН (битумно-полимерная)</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/mastika-prikleivayushhaya-texnonikol-27/">Мастика приклеивающая ТЕХНОНИКОЛЬ № 27</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/prajmer-bitumnyj-aquamast/">Праймер битумный AquaMast</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://o.mdevice.by/product-category/mastika-prajmer-bitum/prajmer-bitumnyj-texnonikol-01/">Праймер битумный ТЕХНОНИКОЛЬ №01</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>  
</header>
```

А это код с двумя дочерними элементами, он прерывается и после него ничего нет.

```
 <header class="sub-menu-head">

    <div class="container clearfix">

        <nav id="sub-menu">

            <ul>
```

В корневом каталоге сайта, в файле error_log содержиться следующая информация:

```
[01-Mar-2016 13:20:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:21:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:25:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:25:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:41 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:26:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:27:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:28:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:01 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[01-Mar-2016 13:30:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[01-Mar-2016 13:31:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 164
[01-Mar-2016 13:31:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 167
[01-Mar-2016 13:31:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 170
[01-Mar-2016 13:31:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_scripts.php on line 173
[01-Mar-2016 13:31:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'header_style' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 245
[03-Mar-2016 12:59:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[03-Mar-2016 13:03:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'slider' in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/pixelstores/sliders/functions.php on line 114
[05-Mar-2016 04:50:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 04:51:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 04:53:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 04:53:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 04:54:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 04:55:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 04:59:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:00:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:00:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:04:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:06:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:06:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:08:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:11:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
[05-Mar-2016 05:16:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare forcha() (previously declared in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php:209) in /home1/newdesig/public_html/o/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php on line 209
```

Comment: Вы ведь не в инстаграмме. Зачем скриншоты. Загружаете страницы, нажимайте `Ctrl`+`U`, публикуйте куски HTML меню. Также смотрите в error_log сервера и покажите ошибки (если есть). Есть у меня подозрение, что во втором случае генерация страницы прерывается.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: И в логах ошибок нету?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Прикрепил логи к вопросу.

Comment: Это пока не ответы. У вас по какой-то причине несколько раз вставляются файлы `wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_functions.php`. Причем, видимо это происходит при добавлении подпунктов в первый пункт меню. Одно из решений - обернуть определение функции в условие. Получится что-то вроде `if (!function_exists('forcha')) { function forcha() { ... } }`

Comment: Весь код (который в functions.php) вставить внутри этой функции?